# php iphone framework?

Tags: php, iphone, frameworks

Is there any PHP framework that will let you code for the iPhone? Like C# (mono touch)

Thank you.

Comment: The iPhone does not run PHP. So, no.

Comment: I am looking for a framework or tool that will let me code in PHP, but convert the code to objective c. The same way phphiphop convert php to c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want, and don't know it yet, is to use a development platform like [Appcellerator's Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) which allows you to use HTML, CSS, Javascript, Ruby and Python to develop native looking apps.

However, to answer your question directly, PHP is not available in any of these types of passthru app development tools as a language to develop iOS apps on.

Best of luck!

Comment: well the Appcellerator's Titanium support PHP for desktop development. I have been working with PHP for a while now and Objective C does not make any sense yet after a year studying it.

Comment: I do not believe this is going to be something Titanium will ever support. You *can* use Javascript libraries though, so jQuery and Dojo, etc. are options if you need more advanced functionality. If you're familiar with .Net/C# then Mono is another option to consider. http://monotouch.net/

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to develop natively for the iPhone with PHP - the platforms are incredibly different. You can, however, still develop iOS-optimized web applications and deploy them as "apps" that have the native look-and-feel with [iOS Web Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/index.html).

Comment: yeah, but I was looking for a way to write native application and not web applications.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. PHP is primarily a web programming language, used to code for web pages. PHP code are usually in text files with a .php extension and are executed by web servers that have access to a PHP interpreter. You can also run PHP code from the command line or compile it into executable code to be distributed, but this is very rarely done. Most compiled programs are written in Java or C++ or C.

iPhone native apps are written in Objective-C and have to be compiled and then uploaded to a device like the iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad. However, you can also create web applications to run on the Safari browser on IOS devices. In the case, you can use PHP but it won't be a native app.

Comment: yeah, but I'm looking for something like PHP HipHop that take the PHP and make it C++.

Comment: There isn't one for PHP->Objective C and a quick Google search in the first place would have answered your question. You might try C or C# instead of PHP if you're so bewildered by Objective-C, but honestly, Objective C is not so unfamiliar once you get the hang of it. It all just boils down to syntax.